# Copula with 4 Poisson and 1 Bernoulli margins in R

Tags: r, copula

I want to joint 4 Poisson variables and 1 Bernoulli variable with D-vine copula. How can I do this with R?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CDVine/vignettes/CDVine-package.pdf